# Store different than display with typeahead input

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I"m trying to implement ANgular typeahead for suppliers.  We have a suppler name and a supplier ID.  I want to display {name} - {ID} in the dropdown, display {name} in the textbox, but store {id} in the model.  Is this possible and how can I do this?

My attempt:

```
 <input id="toSupplier" type="text" ng-model="selectedToSupplier"
                   placeholder="Enter a to supplier name"
                   class="form-control"
                   typeahead="supplier.name as (supplier.name + ' - ' + '[' +  supplier.id + ']') for supplier in getToSuppliers($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-min-length="2"
                   typeahead-loading="Loading" />
```

This gives me what I want in the dropdown, but the name in the model and text box.  I want the id in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try : supplier instead of supplier.name

```
 <input id="toSupplier" type="text" ng-model="selectedToSupplier"
                   placeholder="Enter a to supplier name"
                   class="form-control"
                   typeahead="supplier as (supplier.name + ' - ' + '[' +  supplier.id + ']') for supplier in getToSuppliers($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-min-length="2"
                   typeahead-loading="Loading" />
```

Comment: Tried that as well, but it sets the entire object to the model, instead of just the ID.  Although maybe this is the way to go, and I can change my other code to use `selectedToSuppler.id` instead of `selectedToSupplier`.

Comment: Yes or just use in your typehead supplier.id instead of supplier or supplier.name

Comment: That wouldn't work, then I'll be displaying the ID instead of the name, wouldn't I?

Comment: Try it, (supplier.name + ' - ' + '[' +  supplier.id + ']') would be display and you will store the ID